# using C++11 attributes

Tags: c++, c++11, attributes

Could you please explain how to get information from attributes in C++? For example, I want to write C++ to python binding. For this I need to annotate all methods in class with some specific binding info. Now I need to generate some code by attributes. Or another example, map class to db entity. Or C++11 attributes is not the same as in Java or C# annotations?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Attributes (a [new C++11 feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13781398/827263)) are just a standardized syntax for compiler extensions. To do what you want you would need a compiler with the proper extensions. So far, I don't think any compiler even implements attribute syntax, much less any specific attributes for Python bindings.

Because they're intended for compiler extensions, there's no standard way of creating your own attributes, like you can with Java annotations or C# attributes. Of course, a compiler could provide this ability as an extension... ;)

Comment: That said, one could certainly imagine unknown attributes being placed into debugger metadata.  But they still wouldn't be strongly typed like .NET attributes.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think one could build such functionally as .NET attributes on top of the existing syntax (`[[clang::dotnet_like_attribute(attribute_goes_here(args))]]`), but I'm not expecting it any time soon.

Comment: Where can I find documentation that describes C++11 attributes?

Comment: @AndersonGreen in the [C++11 Standard](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13779444/c%2B%2B-std.pdf), obviously.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes what will be if user try to compile the code with attributes on another compiler? will attributes be ignored?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes  hmm. so we should think about attributes like some optimization tips for compiler, right? or is there any other purpose of attributes?

Comment: @innochenti In general attributes should not change the semantics of a program (because they are ignored in other compilers). So yeah, you can think of them as hints that don't change the observable behaviour, but may help for optimization or some other purpose.

Comment: I would suggest to provide an example just in case.

Answer (score 5):

An update with some more recent information:

GCC now (as of 4.8) implements C++11 attributes as an alternative syntax for `__attribute__((XXX))`.

You can also use the GCC plugin mechanism to define new attributes - see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html.

You can also do this in python using the gcc-python-plugin - see https://gcc-python-plugin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/attributes.html.

Comment: But note that there is a bug in GCC 4.8/4.9 - defining a global attribute through the plugin mechanism will let you use with the `__attribute__((XXX))` syntax, but not the `[[XXX]]` syntax.  Scoped attributes work correctly.  There is a bug filed with the GCC bugzilla.