# Are [[attributes]] new to C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

[using C++11 attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864328/using-c11-attributes) gives a hint that [[attributes]] are new to C++11.

I would like to confirm this: Are attributes new to C++11?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, attributes are a new feature in the 2011 ISO C++ standard; they are not specified in the previous 2003 standard.

They're documented in section 7.6 [dcl.attr] of the standard. A recent draft of the standard is [N3376](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) (PDF, 4.9 MB).

Comment: The accepted answer to [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864328/using-c11-attributes) now says that they're a new feature and links to this answer.