# C++ Is it correct to call class member variables "attributes"?

Tags: c++, methods, attributes, terminology

Can someone please disambiguate class attributes and methods for C++? I was under the impression that attribute means any member variable, and method means any member function.

Thanks

Comment: Attributes = somewhat used but informal terminology.

Comment: I wouldn't use the term `attributes` in C++ that way, since the name `attributes` now refers to a 100% completely unrelated part of the language.

Comment: I don't think it's incorrect, as in "one may not use these words", or as in "they don't hold that meaning in C++". However, the word _attribute_ is being used since C++11 for [something else](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes). As long as you're being clear enough in your terms usage, and you don't stay too far away from existing terminologies, that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Define "correct".**

Referring to data members and member functions as "attributes/properties" and "methods", respectively, is common practice - it's the general OO wording. ("attributes" are used in C++ for [something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864328/using-c11-attributes), though, so this may very well be a source of confusion.)

The C++ standard, however, does **not** use these terms (apart from attributes of course, as explained above). If you don't want to risk anything and always be correct, use "data members" and "member functions".

But if you only want to explain C++ to a Java programmer, you may get away with "property" and "method" in the beginning.

Comment: I would call it **incorrect**. This is not the same case as *method* and *member function*, as there is a concept that is named *attribute* in the C++ standard. That is, if you talk about *method* in C++, people know that *method* has no meaning in C++ and they will default to the OO term. If you use *attribute* in a C++ conversation many people will interpret that you are talking about *attributes* as per the standard.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas So, basically, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282330/c-is-it-correct-to-call-class-member-variables-attributes/18282421?noredirect=1#comment26820325_18282330). (Again, I am not suggesting that using the general terms would be superior to those in the Standard, maybe I should have emphasized this better.)

Comment: Class members are not variables. You may want to replace "member variable" by "data member".

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I had a feeling that "attribute" is not the best word to use anyway... To be honest, I wasn't, however, aware of the fact that standard C++ terminology includes this term.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Thanks, I fixed that, and added further clarification as well.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb What's the distinction between member variable and data member? If `class pie { class fruit apple; bool hot; };` then what would you call `apple` and what would you call `hot`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would not do that. While it can be understood in the general context of OO, it will be confusing in C++ as *attribute* has a precise definition in the standard, that is not that of *data member*.

Answer (score 0):

A class' attributes would translate to its members. A method is not the same as a member function in general. But "In object-oriented programming, a method is a subroutine (or procedure) associated with a class." - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: A method is always associated with a class (although in C++ it is more common to use the word member function).

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineLaFayette: Do you know a "speak" (in the context of compsci langauges) where "method" means something else?

Comment: @MooingDuck I was referring to the generic mathematical / scientific definition of "method".

Answer (score 0):

In common words, an attribute describes something, "One of the attributes of this car is that it's quite long", or "one of the attributes of the giant panda is it's striking black and white colours".

I XML, attributes are used to add extra information in a tag, e.g `<species id=3212>Ailuropoda melanoleuca<common_name>Giant Panda</common_name></species>` - `id` is an attribute, `Ailuropoda melanoleuca` is a value, `common_name` a tag within `species`.

But I call the variables in a class "member variables", and functions in a class "member function" or "method".

Comment: true, "attribute", is commonly associated in english with "characteristic", or "trait" (another word with a specific meaning in C++).