# User-defined attributes in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, attributes, clang++

Is there a way to create user-defined attributes in C++11 or later?

For example,

```
[[noreturn]] void exit();
```

is a compiler-defined C++11 attribute.

I'd like to define something like:

```
[[comingsoon]] int function(int);
```

Is there a mechanism for this?

Edit: I should mention I'm using Clang.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864328/using-c11-attributes).
_Attributes (a new C++11 feature) are just a standardized syntax for compiler extensions. Because they're intended for compiler extensions, there's no standard way of creating your own attributes, like you can with Java annotations or C# attributes._

Comment: It looks like [you can in MSVS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd21828z.aspx) but it is a compiler extension.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's C++/CLI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The language provides no way of adding attributes.

Of course, if you are using Clang, you can edit the source *of Clang*, and add any attributes you like.

Comment: Do you know if there are plans for future versions of C++ to allow users to add attributes?

Comment: I don't know.  I would guess not.  C++ doesn't have the sort of reflection capabilities that would make it useful.

Comment: Not sure this answer remains true.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60e6k732.aspx

Comment: I think that is talking about C++/CLI which is MS's extension to C++.  There is very little chance of that working it's way back into the standard language.

Comment: whats the point of implementing attributes if users cannot define custom ones ? seems like unnecessary bloat

Comment: @orenrevenge - it allows *compiler writers* to add their own.

Answer (score 11):

For now it's not possible to define user-attributes.

There is, as far as i know, no information about if this feature is planned or not.
However, look at this FAQ answer from Stroustrup : https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language-misc#attributes, especially this part :

> One planned use for attributes is improved support for OpenMP. For example:

```
for [ [ omp::parallel() ] ] (int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

It could mean that they plan to allow programmer to define it's own attribute. Wait & see.