# C++ source_annotation_attribute

Tags: c++, attributes, sal

When browsing the source of the open source [.NET Framework 4.7](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/DotNet47RTM.zip) I stumbled across the C++ header `sal.h` and found a line of code saying `[source_annotation_attribute( SA( Method ) )]` which seems to be similar to [attributes and the `AttributesUsage` class in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/attributeusage).

Now I know that generally, there are [no user defined attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34819219/7571171) in C++ as there are in C#, and my first guess was that `[source_annotation_attribute( SA( Method ) )]` is just a macro, but it is neither defined in `sal.h` nor in any other headers, since `sal.h` does not `#include` any.

My next guess is that `[source_annotation_attribute]` is actually built in the MSVC, just like for e.g. [`[[noreturn]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/noreturn) attribute.

I would be glad if somebody could shed some light on what it actually is and if I can declare my own attributes similar to that, if it is not built into the compiler.
If you want to see for your self, the particular file is `\Source\externalapis\legacy\vctools\vc12\inc\vc\sal.h` and the attribute occurs (among others) in line `1934`.

Here is an example on the usage in `sal.h`:

```
[source_annotation_attribute( SA( Method ) )]
struct __M_
{
#ifdef __cplusplus // [
    __M_();
#endif // ]
   int __d_;
};
typedef struct __M_ __M_;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @VTT I added an example on the usage, and I am not sure if that is C++/Cli. It could of course be, but it seems like C++/Cli attributes seem to be [used differently](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd21828z.aspx) from the ones in `sal.h`.

Comment: You should check the block in which this text is present. It has `_MSC_EXTENSIONS` and `_PFT_VER` so it is clearly not a regular c++, maybe it is intended to be used during some special compiler pass.

Comment: @VTT thank you, I believe this is the answer. So I was more right with my second guess, that it is built in to the compiler, too bad. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conclude what @VTT has already said, it looks like the `source_annotation_attribute` is a compiler inbuilt construct, which is shipped as part of a [Microsoft extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/microsoft-extensions-to-c-and-cpp) to C++ 
(even if it is not mentioned there because it is an implementation detail, meant for internal use only) that is valid only when compiled with the compiler switch `/Ze`

What adds to this is the fact that Microsofts [SAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations) is built in deeply in Visual Studio
i.e.

> Build -> Run Code Analysis on Solution
>   and since Visual Studio (obviously) uses their MSVC compiler, it is not too implausible that Microsoft would not build any internal constructs like this in their compilers.